# Run a method in parallel where triggering method can't be overridden

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C#. I have a method in base class that triggers another method that can be override

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
  protected SomeResults processAllItems()
   {
      //code process All Items one by one
      for(Item item : allItems) 
          {  processItem(item);  }
   }

   protected abstract void processItem(Item item);

} 


class MyInheritingClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void processItem(Item item)
    {
       // do my task
    }
}
```

**what I want to do is run processItem() method in parallel. However I cannot override triggering method processAllItems()** I can do something like

```
class MyInheritingClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void processItem(Item item)
    {
       Task.run(() => runTask(item) )
    }

    protected override void runTask(Item item )
    {
       // do my task here
    }

}
```

But I've following concerns

1. processItem will just queue all the items and processAllItems will assume that all the items are processed while they are still running asynchronously
2. If I use task.wait it will fall back to same problem where the items will be processed one by one and not in parallel
   Can someone help me with how can I run processItem in parallel and ensure that the processAllItems will complete only when all the items are processed.
3. can I override processAllItems()?

Comment: Can you change the implementation of `processAllItems()` in your base class?

Comment: define override ? do you mean you cant change the implementation ?

Comment: No. It's a commonly used class
will I be able to override protected SomeResults processAllItems()??

Comment: by override I mean change the implementation of the processAllItems
where I could change the way processItem gets triggered

Comment: Why not make `processAllItems()` virtual so that you can override it?: `protected virtual SomeResults processAllItems()`

Comment: BaseClass is more of a framework class where I cannot make changes

Comment: In that case, it's not really possible to run the processing in parallel. There is the `new` keyword as [SomeBody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64476190/3181933) covers, but I imagine that won't be of much use to you, considering the mentioned drawback.

Comment: This seems like an X/Y Problem...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make `processAllItems()` virtual. In that case, you can override it and change its behaviour in your subclass.

If this is not possible in your case (e.g. because `BaseClass` is part of an external library), you could use the `new` keyword in you subclass:

```
public class MyInheritingClass : BaseClass
{
  protected new SomeResults processAllItems()
   {
      Parallel.ForEach(allItems, processItems);
   }
}
```

But this has a serious drawback:

```
BaseClass test = new MyInheritingClass();
test.processAllItems(); // will call the version of the base class in process in sequence
MyInheritingClass test2 = new MyInheritingClass();
test2.processAllItems(); // will call the version of the subclass in process in parallel
```

You have to check whether you can apply the `new` keyword in your code base.

A completely different solution, which might help you: Do you know what is the last item `allItems`? Then you might do something like this:

```
class MyInheritingClass : BaseClass
{
    private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    protected override void processItem(Item item)
    {
       tasks.Add(Task.run(() => runTask(item) ));
       if(item == lastItem)
       {
          Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
          tasks.Clear();
       }
    }

    protected override void runTask(Item item )
    {
       // do my task here
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this will not work as written above: each instance of MyInheritingClass will have its own 'tasks' list, add only its own 'processItem' task to it . Only 'lastitem will wait for itself to finish...

You might change that behaviour by making 'tasks' static and using lazy instantiation in the constructor...